# Are there US Customs restrictions on buying alcohol online from Spain to be shipped to USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, spain, alcohol, shipping

Are there any USA Customs restrictions involving buying alcohol onlin (specifically two 1-liter bottles of honey rum) from Spain (the Canary Islands) to be shipped to USA (NYC)?

I found an overseas seller and in the process of ordering, they informed me that it can possibly be blocked at US Customs. So I did a few searches and haven't really gotten a concrete answer if it will be a problem or if it is even allowed.

Therefore, 1-are there any restrictions in regards to the above and
2- If allowed, does one have to fill out a form (like one does when traveling on a plane) to declare the two bottles being shipped?
I wouldn't want to complete the order to then find out that customs confiscated the goods.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This isn't really a travel question, however, as you aren't going somewhere and bringing something back. You must, at a minimum, pay federal, state, and local taxes on the goods, or risk having them impounded until you can prove payment. See *[Requirements for importing alcohol for personal use](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-212?language=en_US)* and your state and municipal alcohol control board.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel within the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and possibly cheaper to buy from an [importer](https://1000corks.com/wine/Ron-Miel) in USA?

Comment: I think you may have an issue with U.S. CBP on the federal level. It will depend on: Who you are (business vs personal) and from whom are you getting it; What you are bringing into the country; When you are shipping it (depending on the current political environment); Where is its origin and destination; Why you are bring it in (personal vs commercial); How it will be used (personal use, gift, display, collection, distribution, etc); As well as how it will be shipped. Just as importantly, you will have to check the same rules for your state and possibly local authorities.

Comment: Think of how much of an issue it is to buy or distribute alcohol from one state or county to another. In large volumes, it is even a big issue to transport alcohol between states and counties.

Comment: CBP enforces state import restrictions.  Interstate and international commerce are normally controlled by federal law, but the US constitution puts regulation of alcohol firmly in state hands.  You need to look at both federal and state law, therefore, and at whether you need a state license to import alcohol.